# How to deploy angular9 on GAE

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, angular9

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/askudhay/step-by-step-guide-to-deploy-ngular-app-to-google-app-engine-46hl) step by step. Only get this:
[image]

Here is my `app.yml`

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/fe/index.html
  upload: dist/fe/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: dist/fe

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```

I have no idea why it happens. The angular app runs on the default 4200 port. Is it the cause?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You need to run `npm isntall` and `ng run` commands before deploying the project to GAE.

I also followed the tutorial that you mentioned and got the same result. Upon inspecting the GAE logs I was able to see that 404 errors were taking place, and their messages were `Static file referenced by handler not found: dist/pounds-to-kg/index.html`

The `ng run` command builds the project and creates the `dist/` folder that stores all the artifacts